# How can I remove certain rows in a CSV file if they are string type rather than numeric?

Tags: csv, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have a dataset with 10 columns, two of which are supposed to be port numbers (numeric). The dataset is large with over 1 million rows. Is there a way I can quickly remove the rows where the sport or dport values are strings instead of numbers?

Comment: What programming language are you using? Many different languages have ways to compare a value to check if it is alphanumeric in their standard libraries. You can just check for that while parsing the csv.

Comment: Python is what I would be most comfortable with - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of using GoCSV which provides a number of functions like the one you're looking for.

It's a command-line tool and its [filter command](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv#filter) will do just what you want.

I mocked up this simple CSV:

```
Id,sport,dport
1,,443
2,8080,
3,Foo,22
4,9999,
5,Bar,
6,444,Baz
```

and I run this:

```sh
gocsv filter -c 'sport','dport' -regex '[^\d]' -exclude input.csv
```

That's filtering for any row that matches the regular expression "has a non-digit" in either the 'sport' or 'dport' columns, and then excludes that row (inverts the filter)...

...and I get this output:

```
Id,sport,dport
1,,443
2,8080,
4,9999,
```

It can be installed by going to [its release page](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv/releases/tag/v1.0.1) and downloading the pre-built binary for your OS/architecture.